# Birt 3.7.2 totalPage not working

Tags: birt

I have a Birt Report with a data element "Page " + pageNumber + " of " + totalPage in the Layout but it keeps giving me output of "Page 1 of 1" or "Page 2 of 2". Is there a way to correct this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

totalPage is only known at "render" time, so we cannot use it like this in expressions. A workaround is to use "onRender" script. click your data element->Script->onRender:

```
this.setDisplayValue("Page " + pageNumber + " of " + totalPage);
```

Or for a dynamic text element instead of a data element:

```
this.text="Page " + pageNumber + " of " + totalPage
```

Comment: Sorry doesn’t work... it still shows Page 1 of 1, Page 2 of 2

Comment: sorry i know why it does not work i run the birt viewer as run instead of frameset

Answer (score 0):

Page number variable works in rptlibrary.

Use page number and total page from library in your layout wherever required.